# SAS Macro code to Pig/Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am working on converting SAS programs to Hadoop ie. Pig or Hive, and I am having trouble converting the macro code in SAS to something in hive. Is there any equivalent for the same since I already read that Hive does not support Stored Procedures? I need to write a hive script which has a macro code like function to call variables and use in the script.

Comment: This is very unclear. Please share a small data sample including the requested results and describe the data processing logic.

Comment: I do not have a sample data set since I am working on my company data. SAS macro calls are separate programs in itself, which are called within a SAS program. I need similar calling functionality for certain variables while writing a create table... statement in hiveql.

Comment: You are trying to force a technical solution that you use on another system instead of describing a real issue and let others to advice you.

Comment: I am just trying to find if there is a way out for it. I know I am not helping much but just wanted some advice on what are the possibilities.

Comment: You can use Hive and Hive does support dynamic variables (search `hivevar`) in between Hive queries. For looping or doing other SAS `data step` operations you need to rely on shell scripting.

Comment: Ok. That helps a lot! Thank you... :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to write the macro code in an if...else statement within Hive itself. Thanks guys for all the help! I know the question was not that greatly put up, but I will learn over time.